# RDLC without table or tablix, showing only First record

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, rdlc

I am creating a check printing RDLC. Since the report format cannot be achieved through table / tablix, I have put four text boxes in body area of the report and linked them with columns.

Now, when I run the report, I only see the first record being displayed in the layout.

If I create a report with table or tablix, it shows all entries.

Any work-around to get all records without table / tablix. I am using non-aggregate field name already (e.g. `=Fields!CheckDate.Value`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `List` which is basically a `Tablix` with only one cell containing a `Rectangle`.

Inside a `Rectangle` you can put any control in the position you want. You can also set page break after every element.

[image: list]

Comment: Excellent. Thanks a lot, you saved the day.